# Craft 3 Image Editor / Redactor - Remove?

Tags: craft3, assets, redactor, editor

**TL;DR**
Can the button for "**Image Editor**" be removed from Redactor in Craft 3?

---

I've looked around the Craft docs and web, but I can't find a way to remove the button that appears within the Redactor when an image is clicked.

[image]

At first glance it seems like Redactor's `imageEditable` config should just be set to `false`, but unfortunately that only removes a small amount of features in the "edit" modal, not "Image editor" button itself [below].
https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/image/#s-imageeditable

[image]

Has anyone tried to remove option for **Image Editor** before? Is this even possible?